# MenuItem of ContextMenu set disable doesn't work javafx

Tags: javafx, menuitem

I do following:

```
row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
        startMenuItem.setDisable(true);
    }
});
```

But menuItem `disableProperty` is false.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? Just from your code I would guess that your event was not `MouseButton.SECONDARY`, but it's hard to tell from here. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions.

Comment: @SteveHeim I check it and **event.getButton()** is **MouseButton.SECONDARY**